# Need help disabling imessage?

Tags: messages

I recently changed from iphone to android and i have been having trouble recieving messages from my iphone friends since my iphones screen is broken i cant do anything on it. Any way to fix this problem through icloud or something?

Answer (score 1):

https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage

This will allow you to de register the old number from iMessage.